# how to setup playwright webserver configuration?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am working with playwright. I'm new to use playwright. In playwright documentation, it is written that 'Playwright comes with a webserver option in the config file which gives you the ability to launch a local dev server before running your tests. This is ideal for when writing your tests during development and when you don't have a staging or production URL to test against.'. I'm confused about that. Does playwright provides an internally built server or do we need to specify a server file in the package.json file and then it will start that server?

this is my playwright.config.js.

```
const { defineConfig, devices } = require('@playwright/test');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {

    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },
  ],
  webServer: {
    command: 'npm run start',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    reuseExistingServer: true,
  },
});
```

My question is when I run 'npx playwright test', will it start a server that is internally built-in playwright, or do we need to mention a start script in the package.json file to start a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playwright can't know what your application does or needs to be started, and it does not have a built-in webserver.

That's why you have to configure a `command` in your Playwright config to run and test your project.

Comment: thanks for your guidence, do you mean to say that i will have to configure command in 'package.json' file and also mention a server file where we have setup a server like we do in expressjs?

Comment: Sorta. The way it should work is that you'd define a command that starts a webserver in your `package.json` (e.g. `npm start`) and playwright then will run this command before starting the tests.

Comment: sorry im confused with that, i have package.json file,
i can write a "start" script inside this file. but i would need to mention some file to run with this script, right? same like what we do while running an expressjs server?

{
  "name": "voipbusiness-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "node server.js"
},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.34.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.1"
  }
}
like above?

Comment: Yes. The `command` property accepts any shell command to run a webserver. `node server.js` does work, too.

Comment: Happy to, can you mark the answer as solution if it was helpful?